# Systematic way of deriving minimax lower bounds using Fano's inequality

Tags: regression, estimation

My question is specific to the point in derivations where the domain is reduced to a finite set of distributions/indices so that the Fano's inequality can be applied. I wonder if there is a systematic way to choose a reasonable set in general, particularly when the desired lower bound is not already known.